# Sharepoint Mobile App and form based authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication, 2016, mobile

Can someone shed some light on how to login to Sharepoint mobile app when the site is FBA enabled?

We have an on-prem SP2016, and the site is FBA enabled. I just noticed that the SP mobile app is unable to login to this site. Another web application that does not use FBA can log in fine. This is why I'm suspecting it's the FBA. Microsoft blog says the app support FBA, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. Thanks in advance for the answer!